# nosql inconsistent data structure

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to nosql (MongoDB) so go easy on me.

I'm scraping json-ld from various web pages and want to store/recall the data.  However the value types keep changing.  For instance sometimes the "author" field uses an "organization" type, other times it's a "person" type sometimes it's simply a string, and sometimes it's just missing.

Should I convert the data to some type of standard?
Should each object be put into it's own collection and referenced?
How do you deal with displays being different.

Looking for words of experience or links to good articles on how to deal with inconsistent data structure.

Comment: This is an open-ended question. Sounds like you're dealing with semi-structured data. Using your example, ideally, `author` should be consistent, e.g. typically this is a `string` type or similar. However, this is sometimes not possible if you have multiple data sources. MongoDB's document model can handle your requirement regarding varying data types for the same field, however it's best to learn more about MongoDB to see if it is a good fit for your use case. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/ for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of No-Sql database is that its schema less, and the structure can vary from document to other, so I see no issue in here.

I think you are asking on how you should deal with it in your application business logic, so here is my suggestion:

You can save the author as an embedded sub-document which always have a field called “type” (as an enum of values: String, Person, Organization, etc…) and act accordingly when you fetch the data.

For example, if the author is simply a String then the document would look like something like:

```
{
…,
 “author”: {
    “type”: “String”,
    “text”: <text>
 }
}
```

If its a Person type then:

```
{
…,
 “author”: {
    “type”: “Person”,
    “first_name”: <first name>,
    “last_name”: <last name> 
 }
}
```